# Regex all even numbers, highest number 12

Tags: regex

I'm trying to get a regex to get only even numbers and the highest number that can be entered should be 12.

I got this to work for only even number:

```
^(\d*[02468])$
```

Now I just need help with getting the highest number that can be entered is 12.  I tried:

```
^(\d*[02468]|[0-1][0-2])$
```

but that didn't work.  Any suggestions?

Comment: You'd better just use `^([02468]|1[02])$`

Comment: The `\d*` is zero or more numbers so `\d*[02468]` allows any amount of numbers preceding the even number. e.g. `12`, `112`, `1112`.

Comment: This is the kind of task where regex is not a good solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `^(\d*[02468]|[0-1][0-2])$` regex matches (with `\d*[02468]`) 0 or more digits followed with `0`, `2`, `4`, `6` (so, it can match `32`) or (with `[0-1][0-2]`) `8` or `00`, `01`, `02`, `10`, `11` or `12`. As you see, they are not all even.

You may use

```
^([02468]|1[02])$
```

Or with a leading optional `0`:

```
^(0?[02468]|1[02])$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DCEuzL/1)

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(` - Grouping construct matching either

  - `[02468]` - a digit from the set
  - `|`  0- or
  - `1[02]` - `10` or `12`
- `)`  -  end of group
- `$` - end of string

Comment: Got it...makes sense.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Just list all the valid numbers: `^(0|2|4|6|8|10|12)$`. It's not the shortest solution but the most easy to read and understand.